# Husky A200 crashed after Ubuntu 12.04 and Fuerte update

Tags: a200, ubuntu, husky, ros-fuerte, rosmaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I updated the onboard mini-ITX PC in Husky A200 with Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte today. while the installations were successful and i was able to complete all the procedures including the download of clearpath packages for Ubuntu 12.04 the system repeatedly keeps saying

"unable to communicate with the master"

Initially I downloaded the various clearpath packages for husky including,

ros-fuerte-clearpath-husky-robot

ros-fuerte-clearpath-husky

ros-fuerte-clearpath-common

ros-fuerte-clearpath-kinect

I performed the steps provided in [husky page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Husky) which is briefly mentioned below.

```
roscd clearpath_common
sudo ./setup_udev.bash
roscd clearpath_bringup/upstart
sudo ./install.bash eth0 administrator husky_bringup
```

And finally,

```
sudo service clearpath start
```

However, for any further ROS command it mostly says,

```
unable to communicate with the master!
```

Interestingly I found that the install.bash file for fuerte also contains the name electric in several places. Should I modify this to fuerte instead?

Looking for some suggestions on restoring the communications in Husky,

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39579/husky-a200-crashed-after-ubuntu-12.04-and-fuerte-update/) by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 612 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-07-23**:
Could you include the different ways you've already tried to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I found that the mistake I found was absolutely correct. Replacing the name of electric in the install.bash file with fuerte solves the problem.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1